# What is the difference between bitmask and bitmap in C

Tags: c

What is the conceptual difference between them? I know bitmap is sort of bitfields in the structs..

```
struct{
    int bit1: 1;
    int bit2: 1;
    int bit3: 1;
  };
```

so in tht case is bitmask something we define for an enum?

Comment: Neither "bitmap" nor "bitmask" are words used in the C spec. "bitfield" is, and your example does show one.  Can you explain what you're trying to ask?

Answer (score 14):

A bitmask is an integer type that is used to "mask" certain bits when performing bitwise operations.  For example, the bitmask `0xFFFFFFFF` might be used to mask a 32-bit unsigned value because you want to operate on all bits at once, whereas `0x00000001` would only operate on the very last bit.  You often see bitmasks defined as the 'flipped' version and then flipped using `~`.

A bitmap, on the other hand, is a set of variables each mapped to an individual bit.  There are many ways of achieving this, your struct is one (common) example of a bitmap.

You might put various masks in an enum to give yourself easier access to them, but it's not strictly necessary to do so.

Comment: Strictly speaking, bitmap files are also just arbitrary bits of data [pun intended] - it's only when your software interprets them as image data and displays them on a monitor -- or prints them out -- that they become an image.  But yes, the .bmp extension and image/bmp mime type (colloquially, a "bitmap file") are both used to identify data as being something that the author of the data intended to be interpreted as image data.

Answer (score 3):

Bitmap is more of data itself which comprise of bits.
One of the example could be say that there are **8 friends** in a **group** and group performs various activities together.
Group participation in each activity now can be represented by "bitmap" which comprise of bits (each for one friend).
e.g.

`Skii - 10110000 <<<<friend  5,6 and 8 will go to Skii`

`Movie - 10011000 <<< friend 4,5 and 8 will go to movie`

`College- 11111111 <<<all friends will go to college`

Bitmask is more skeleton for bitmap. bitmask will be used to set and get bit values in bitmap.

`friend1 - 00000001<<<< bitmask for friend 1`

`friend2 - 00000010 <<<bitmask for friend 2`

`friend5 - 00010000`

(Note: I found it awkward to address friend0 :) , purist may consider everything as n-1)

Now using bitmap and bitmask we can determine

- is friend1 going for Skii?

`Skii & friend1 <<<< this would be zero`

- is friend 5 going to Movie?

`Movie & friend5 <<< yes`

Comment: Interesting explanation on using bitmaps and bitmasks together. pretty cool. thanks